# Can a K-type thermocouple measure both air and surface temperatures?

Tags: arduino, sensor, temperature, thermocouple

I want to use a K-type thermocouple to measure exhaust gas temperature and surrounding structure temperatures for my micro turbo jet engine.

I read in the comments of [How to use MAX6675 thermocouple k type with Arduino](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGqONmUinqA&ab_channel=Robojax) video the following:

[image]

From what I understand, a thermocouple is simply two different metal rods which are connected to a small bulb at one end where they are in thermal equilibrium and produce a voltage output at the other ends.

I do not understand why it would be the case that it can only be used to measure air temperature alone and will have problems measuring surface temperatures.

Comment: It sounds like you did not understand their response because they actually did imply the reason. Being encased in a rods makes it difficult to mount to flat surfaces with good contact. Rods are better for fluids.

Comment: @DKNguyen I had not understood what was meant by heat transfer compound and its use. So what I understand after your comment is that the rod would not have proper contact with the surface. So to improve heat transfer from the surface to the sensor we need to put some heat transfer compound. This would improve sensor readings?

Comment: Heat transfer compound would work better than nothing but still won't work terribly well on a rod because heat transfer compound is meant to fill small gaps between two flat surfaces, not fill fillets between a cylinder and a flat surface. And all the extra thermal mass of the rod isn't required either if you're not dunking it into a fluid.

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks! So as long as I can make sure that there is proper heat transfer between the surface and the sensor I am good, right?

Comment: Yes although you also want to reduce unnecessary thermal mass.

Comment: @DKNguyen. What is "unnecessary thermal mass"?

Comment: The long metal rod. More mass means it is slower to reach the temperature of the target and also affects the temperature of the target more. Ideally you want the thermocouple assembly to be as small as possible so it reacts as quickly as possible and influences the temperature of what you're measuring as little as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137182/discussion-between-atharva-and-dknguyen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason a thermocouple can't be used to measure surface temperature. This is done all the time.

However, note that the air and the thermocouple wires will be conducting some heat to the thermocouple in addition to the surface, and that can affect the reading.

Creating a good thermal bond between the thermocouple and the surface will minimize the error. Thermal epoxy may work at low temperatures. At high temps, I would try to weld or mechanically clamp the thermocouple to the surface.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different constructions of thermocouples. A thermocouple is simply two dissimilar metals joined at one point. Anything beyond that is optional.

If you want to measure temperature up to maybe 1200°C you could use an open junction K thermocouple in the gas stream, and it would respond relatively quickly if the wire gauge is small, however the life may not be what you would like (it matters whether the gas is reducing or oxidizing). Another construction is a sheath with ceramic powder and the junction contained within the welded end of the sheath. The sheath can be made of a high nickel superalloy. That probably won't work well to measure gas temperature in a small cross section because the sheath will draw too much heat from the junction. It has to be immersed 5 or (ideally) 10 diameters to get good coupling.

There are better materials such as platinum-rhodium alloys (types R, S, B) that work well with small gauges and high temperatures but they are more expensive and the voltage output at a given temperature is much less than with base metal thermocouples such as K (Chromel-Alumel).